# Binding Tooltip to each item of WPFToolkit DropDownColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, wpftoolkit

How to bind tooltip text to each item of A dropdown inside the WPFToolkit's DataGrid.

i m using following Code

```
<WPFtoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgCboTransformation" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="125" 
                                             Header="Transformation" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Signature"
                                             SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Transformation}" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                             ToolTipService.IsEnabled="true">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Path=Signature}"/>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ItemContainerStyle.

Here is how I've done this in the past to individually enable an item in a CheckListBox

```
<wpf:CheckListBox>
  <wpf:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpf:CheckListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="{Binding Path=LogisticareIDIsValid}" />
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                Handler="listResultsDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
  </wpf:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</wpf:CheckListBox>
```